# Prevent the user from entering many dots

Tags: android

I am making a calculator app in android studio. I need to prevent user from entering many dots.

here is my code for the dot button what should I add more ?

```
public void Buttondotclick(View v) {

    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    textview1.setText(textview1.getText() + ".");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be to check if a dot is already entered:

```
public void Buttondotclick(View v) {
    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (!textview1.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
        textview1.setText(textview1.getText() + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: @marvken If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!